# JavaScript injection with powershell (jQuery doesn't load in time)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've injected some script references into my SharePoint pages using `PowerShell` with `PnP PS snap-ins`. When I inspect the head element `jQuery` is listed as the first of my custom scripts.

The problem is, on some pages, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

I've tried to use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, '/path/to/jQuery');` and also `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, jquery.min.js);` but neither of them seems to execute, even though jQuery is loaded when I check the network tab in chrome dev. tools.

Can someone point me to the right direction on how to execute scripts only after jquery is loaded? It seems like SharePoint (online) loads the scripts in the head tag asynchronous?

Comment: On a side note, not related to custom action: In order to use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` you'll have to modify your `jquery.min.js` file and add `NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("myCustomKey");` , in your case it would be `NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("jquery.min.js");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To check your issue**

You can check the loading order of all scripts by using chrome's network tab. 
The first script there (excluding inline code) is the first one executed.

**General tip**

In almost any case where I have to add .js / .css to sharepoint I solve it in 2 ways:

1. Using `CustomActions` of location `ScriptLink` (add your CSS via JS) where you can use the sequence to modify the order of your scripts.
2. Adding Tags to the .master so you can manage the order directly

Here's some JavaScript for you to quickly set up a custom action (just copy it in your browser):

```
(function(_){
    _.settings = {
        actionName: 'SomeUniqueIdentifier', //should be unique cz its used to identify your CA later
        scriptLink: '~siteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/yourscript.js', //needs to be relative
        description: 'Never actually shown but you can fill it for more interna information (versioning, etc.)' 
    };

    _.addCustomAction = function(){
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var site = clientContext.get_site();
            var caCollection = site.get_userCustomActions();

            var ca = caCollection.add();
            ca.set_location('ScriptLink');
            ca.set_sequence(100);
            ca.set_title(_.settings.actionName);
            ca.set_description(_.settings.description);
            ca.set_scriptSrc(_.settings.scriptLink);
            ca.update();
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                console.log('custom action added');
            }, function (sender, args) {
                debugger;
            });

        });
    };

    //remove all custom actions at level site (use with caution!)
    _.deleteCustomAction = function(){
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var site = clientContext.get_site();
            var caCollection = site.get_userCustomActions();

            clientContext.load(caCollection);

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                var caEnum = caCollection.getEnumerator();

                while (caEnum.moveNext()) {
                    var ca = caEnum.get_current();
                        ca.deleteObject();                      

                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                            console.log('Custom action removed');
                        }, function (sender, args) {
                            console.log(args);
                            debugger;
                        });

                }
            }, function (sender, args) {
                console.log(args);
                debugger;
            });

        });
    };
    window.caUtil = _;
})({})

//use it like this: 
caUtil.addCustomAction();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think I'll stick with the [PnP-powershell](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/AddSPOJavaScriptLink.md) pattern for now, if @Anders Aunes answer works for me . What I didn't know before I dug up this link again right now, is that there is a sequence parameter in the command, so if I can use that in order to change the loading of the scripts, your post helped me understand the PS command, and loading of scripts in sharepoint better :)

Comment: @Chris if you follow the code of your library it is using CustomActions behind the scenes ;) glad I could help you